# How to do "case when exists..." in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What I am trying to do is

```
case when exists (select 1 from table B where A.id = B.id and B.value in (1,2,3)) then 'Y' else 'N' end as Col_1
```

It seems like "left semi join" can take care of multiple matching issue, but my understanding is that "left semi join" does not allow using columns from the right (B) table, so how can I add condition "B.value in (1,2,3)"?

Comment: What you're trying to do inside CASE is INNER join only, and you would be able to use the condition filter on B table as you've shown. What issue are you running into?

Comment: What is the issue with your code?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff My understanding is that spark sql only accepts subquery in where clause, so I cannot do "case when exists (subquery)" here

Comment: @Rajeev Pande, Not exactly, inner join will generate additional records when there are multiple matching, which I dont not want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to do this is to left outer join to a summary of table b:

```
Select a.id, Case When IsNull(b.id) Then 'N' else 'Y' end as Col_1
From A Left Outer Join 
    (Select distinct id from tableb) b On A.id=b.id
```

That way you are not repeatedly executing a lookup query for every id in A.

**Addition**
Your comment indicated that you are trying to create multiple Y/N columns based on b values.  Your example had a Y/N for col1 when there was a 1,2,3 and a Y/N for col2 when there was a 4,5,6.
You can get there easily with one summarization of table b :

```
Select a.id, Case When IsNull(b.val123) Then 'N' else 'Y' end as Col_1,
             Case When IsNull(b.val456) Then 'N' Else 'Y' end as Col_2
From A Left Outer Join 
    (Select id, max(Case When value in (1,2,3) Then 'Y' End) as val123
            max(Case When value in (4,5,6) Then  'Y' End) as val456
     From tableb
     Group By id) b On A.id=b.id
```

This still accomplishes that lookup with only one summarization of table b.

Comment: thanks. I figured this might be the only solution for now. the reason I was trying to avoid this is that I have many different conditions on table B like 'B.value in (1,2,3)' for col_1,   'B.value in (4,5,6)' for col_2, etc. and I dont want create many different summary of table b and left outer joins

Comment: OK, so change the summarization of table b.  Something like, Select id, max(case when value in (1,2,3) Then 'Y' End) as val123, max(case when value in (4,5,6)  Then 'Y' End) as val456 From table b Group by id.  Then you test for isnull(b.id) OR Isnull(b.val123) OR Isnull(b.val456).

Comment: awesome. I believe this will work. Thanks